# Is there an easier way to do a "Cascading Insert" in SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I inherited SQL code that I need to work on that was set up similar to the following:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Ni](
    [FooID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Bar] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    [LocationID] [int] NULL,
    [Thing1] [float] NULL
CONSTRAINT [PK_Ni] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [FooID] ASC
);

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UQ_LocationBar] ON [dbo].[Ni]
(
    [LocationID] ASC,
    [Bar] ASC
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Ni_Two](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FooID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Thing2] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Thing3] [int] NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT [PK_Ni_Two] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
);

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Ni_Two]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_NiTwo_FooID] FOREIGN KEY([FooID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Ni] ([FooID]);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[KillMe](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FooID] [int] NULL,
    [Thing4] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Thing5] [int] NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
);

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[KillMe]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_KillMe_FooID] FOREIGN KEY([FooID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Ni] ([FooID]);


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PleaseStop](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [KillMeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Thing7] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Thing8] [int] NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
);

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PleaseStop]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_PleaseStop_KillMe] FOREIGN KEY([KillMeID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[KillMe] ([ID]);
```

At issue is that with this design is with `[Ni].dbo.[Bar]`. That unique constraint is put in there as a requirement. Every `FooID` is unique, and every `Bar` assigned to `LocationID` must be unique.

Now the requirements have changed. With each quarterly import there will be a few entries where the `Bar` field must be updated.

I have tried:

```
   UPDATE dbo.[Ni]
   SET   Bar                 = Imp.Bar
       , LocationID          = Imp.LocationID
       , Thing1              = Imp.Thing1
   FROM dbo.[Ni]
       INNER JOIN ImportData Imp ON [Ni].FooID = Imp.FooID
```

This will give me a `Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint` error.

I don't want to change the schema because I don't know what other effects it will have on the code. The author of the program has since left the company . . . and here I am.

The program runs quarterly (I.E. four times a year) as part of a maintenance routine.

Can I do this without using `WHILE` statements? Because that's going to be a pain.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no version 18 of SQL Server. You've also tagged [[tag:sql-server-2016]], which is version 13. What are you really using?

Comment: I mis-read the "About" screen when looking for the version info.

Comment: You probably read it correctly, but that's the version of SSMS (the client tool you're using to connect to SQL Server).  For the version of the SQL Server instance itself run `SELECT @@VERSION;`

Comment: What do you mean by " Bar has to be renamed."?

Comment: SQL Server 16, SP 2

Comment: I added an edit to clarify "Bar has to be renamed" (I was rushed in writing this)

Comment: For the record, here is how far I've gotten: Assume some entry has a `bar` field that needs to be changed, I know enough to store the entry for all tables on some kind of temp tables with the new `bar` field entry. I know the order in which to remove the current rows. And I know the order to enter the new rows. The tables have a 1:Many relationship. In my first crack at it, the amount of code is just ungodly.

Comment: So why can't you simply update Bar?

Comment: It gives me a `Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint` error. I'll edit the question for clarification.

Comment: Am I allowed to disable and re-enable the constraint in a stored procedure? Or does that have to be performed outside of the SP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So either update them all in a single query, eg

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Ni](
    [FooID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Bar] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    [LocationID] [int] NULL,
    [Thing1] [float] NULL
CONSTRAINT [PK_Ni] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [FooID] ASC
)
);

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UQ_LocationBar] ON [dbo].[Ni]
(
    [LocationID] ASC,
    [Bar] ASC
);

insert into Ni(bar) values ('a'),('b'),('c');

with newValues as
(
  select * from (values (1,'c'),(3,'x')) newValues (FooId, Bar)
),
toUpdate as
(
  select ni.FooId, ni.Bar, NewValues.Bar NewBar
  from Ni
  join NewValues 
    on ni.FooID = newValues.FooId
)  
update toUpdate set Bar = NewBar
```

or disable and rebuild the unique index

```
begin transaction
alter index [UQ_LocationBar] on ni disable
update ni set bar = 'b' where fooid = 1
update ni set bar = 'a' where fooid = 2
alter index [UQ_LocationBar] on ni rebuild
commit transaction
```

> Am I allowed to disable and re-enable the constraint in a stored procedure?

It requires additional permissions, of course, but there's no restriction on running DDL inside a stored procedure, and in SQL Server DDL is fully transactional, so you can commit/rollback to prevent partial updates and to prevent other sessions from seeing partial results.

Comment: I would prefer the second option as long as I know that it's going to affect anything else on rebuild. I'll give a try on the dev site.

Comment: Alright, lets see if our org put any restrictions on what I can do!

Comment: That ran without errors . . . that's a good thing. I think you solved my headache. I have to do some secondary checks before giving this the golden checkmark.

Comment: Yup! That got me there. Thanks man! Here's your checkmark! The second solution is the one I went with.